Lunar power transmission using bare conductors laid on the regolith?
Electrical power transmission on the lunar surface will likely become necessary to join solar farms and lunar facilities, especially if water hydrolysis  is used to make hydolox propellant.
Construction of conventional power lines with pylons and suspended cables would be a significant undertaking. Solar radiation is damaging to many common insulation materials. The large temperature fluctuations from lunar night to day (-175C to +127C) would change the tension in suspended wires.
Why not just lay the bare conductors on the ground? Regolith has about the same dielectric constant as Teflon or cross-linked polyethylene (2.35 vs 2.02 and 2.5) so regolith is an excellent insulator.
https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/14/18/4539#:~:text=The%20relative%20dielectric%20constant%20of,rocks%20in%20the%20landing%20site https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7508671
Moonwalkers would need to take a giant leap over the conductors, unless the wires were trenched.
The illustration below is from a posted question which proposed a circum-lunar power transmission line using conventional suspended conductors..

Mass of a circumlunar power transmission line?

Interesting. If that’s the case, I would have a follow up question about how any reasonably large electrical network would be grounded properly if it’s such an effective insulator.

@fyrepenguin ,,, the lunar "ground" is so poorly conductive it cannot be used, as we do on Earth, as a conductor. (eg: Single-wire earth return (SWER). A neutral conductor would be needed.

@fyrepenguin Good question. I assume that it's similar to grounding in an aircraft or spacecraft. There's some info at https://monroeaerospace.com/blog/how-are-airplanes-electrically-grounded And more spacecraft-related info at Electrical Grounding Practices for Aerospace Hardware https://llis.nasa.gov/lesson/658

I imagine that depends on how much power you're moving and how far. The distances involved might be rather short (at first...) but electrolysis requires a pretty hefty amount of juice.

I would worry about plasma discharge, especially if they were at high voltage -- just because it's a vacuum, doesn't mean it will be reliably a good vacuum near outgassey equipment and operations that may be venting waste gases.

Regolith has about the same dielectric constant as Teflon or cross-linked polyethylene, but we don't want to build a capacitor, we need a good insulation material between the conductors. Therefore the bulk resistance of the regolith should be very high in comparison with Teflon.
